# Serve root static file with nginx as node reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, configuration

I have a nodejs server that's served with nginx as reverse proxy. That part is ok, and static files locations are set up correctly. But I want the root address to serve a static html file, and I don't know how to configure nginx so that the root url is not redirectected to the node app. Here's my server block:

```
upstream promotionEngine {
 server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;
    root C:/swaven/dev/b2b.pe/promotionEngine/templates/;
    index index.html;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://promotionEngine;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /public/ {
      alias C:/swaven/dev/b2b.pe/promotionEngine/public/;
    }

    location /assets/ {
      alias C:/swaven/dev/b2b.pe/promotionEngine/assets/;
    }
}
```

htttp://localhost:3000/ping and http://localhost:3000/public/js/riot.js are correctly served.
But http://localhost:3000 keeps being sent to the node server, where I would like it to return a static index.html. If I remove the / location bloc, the html file is correctly served. How would I configure the location to work as reverse proxy for all urls except the root one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**: (based on comments and discussion)

You'll need 2 exact location blocks. One to intercept the `/` location and another to serve just `/index.html`.

An exact location block is described on [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> Also, using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates.

Simply using the `index` directive does not work. Because nginx [creates an internal redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html) to allow other blocks to match `index.html`. Which gets picked up by your proxy block.

```
upstream promotionEngine {
 server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;

    # Do an exact match on / and rewrite to /index.html
    location = / {
      rewrite ^$ index.html;
    }

    # Do an exact match on index.html to serve just that file
    location = /index.html {
      root C:/swaven/dev/b2b.pe/promotionEngine/templates/;
    }

    # Everything else will be served here
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://promotionEngine;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /public/ {
      alias C:/swaven/dev/b2b.pe/promotionEngine/public/;
    }

    location /assets/ {
      alias C:/swaven/dev/b2b.pe/promotionEngine/assets/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the new location, but now I get a `{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/index.html does not exist"}`. So the location is visited, but it still processes the `\\`` location after that. Even with a `break` directive.

Comment: hmm is the `alias` path in the `location = /` block set to the directory which contains the index.html file?

Comment: oh, also you should be sending a request to `localhost:3000`, **not** `localhost:3000/index.html` that would match the second location block

Comment: Ah looks like this is the problem: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html If you read the bottom part, looks like `index` causes a redirect which then causes the second route to match...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84153/discussion-between-antoine-and-sanketh-katta).

Answer (score 1):

You can use *=/* this type of location have higher priority due to lookup:

```
location =/ {
  root ...
}
```

This request will not even try to reach other locations.

Answer (score -1):

```
Something like this, adjust for your own use case.

http {
    map $request_uri $requri {
        default          1;
        /                0;
    }
...........
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.mydomain.eu;
        root   '/webroot/www.mydomain.eu’;
        if ($requri) { return 301 https://www.mydomain.eu$request_uri; }
        location / {
            ..........
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but I understand if directives are bad: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: An IF should only be used to return a single state like shown above, IF is evil when used to continue config evaluation/operation. The above example is EXACTLY what an IF is meant to be used for and does not warrant by ANY example a -1. ea. [if (xx) { a; b; c; ... } is bad, only 'a' is ok]